# Find a document using nested property in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

Having a document of this form

```
{ "id" : 1,
  "data": "some_data"
}
```

the method I'm using to find it is this one

```
myModel.findOne({ id: req.params.id})
```

this works fine, but now the model has changed and it looks like this

```
{  "item": {
       "id": 1
    },
   "data": "some_data",
}
```

tying [like this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/) doesn't seem to work:

```
myModel.findOne({ item: { id: req.params.id } })
```

any ideas?

Comment: have you tried: myModel.findOne({ 'item.id': req.params.id})

Comment: that's working! please write it as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
myModel.findOne({ 'item.id': req.params.id})
```